# DRY version of similar string processing

Tags: python

What would be a more efficient way to do the following:

```
directors = get_element_or_none(title_node, 'Director')
producers = get_element_or_none(title_node, 'Producer')
writers = get_element_or_none(title_node, 'Writer')

if directors:
    directors = [director.strip() for director in directors.split(',')]
if producers:
    producers = [producer.strip() for producer in producers.split(',')]
if writers:
    writers = [writer.strip() for writer in writers.split(',')]
```

Comment: What *part* of the following?

Comment: Note that your `directors`, etc. are either *something* falsy or a list; shouldn't that always be a list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To always produce a list (possibly empty):

```
directors = [director.strip() for director in directors.split(',')] if directors else []
# etc.
```

or use `map(str.strip, ...)`:

```
directors = map(str.strip, directors.split(',')) if directors else []
```

but in Python 3 that requires an explicit call to `list()`:

```
directors = list(map(str.strip, directors.split(','))) if directors else []
```

because `map()` returns an iterator instead.

or use a helper function:

```
def tolist(commaseparated):
    return [s.strip() for s in commaseparated.split(',')] if commaseparated else []

directors = tolist(directors)
producers = tolist(producers)
writers   = tolist(writers)
```

or, with the map version:

```
def tolist(commaseparated):
    return map(str.strip, commaseparated.split(',')) if commaseparated else []
```

The split-and-strip operation could probably be merged into one function with the `get_element_or_none()` call, but that depends on what else you might use the `tolist()` functionality for.

Answer (score 0):

Not very radical but:

```
def clean_element(node, tag):
    elements  = get_element_or_none(node, tag)
    if elements:
        elements = [element.strip() for element in elements.split(',')]
    return elements


directors = clean_element(title_node, 'Director')
producers = clean_element(title_node, 'Producer')
writers   = clean_element(title_node, 'Writer')
```

As radical as a bike with two wheels.

```
import functools
get_them  = functools.partial(clean_element, title_node)

directors = get_them('Director')
producers = get_them('Producer')
writers   = get_them('Writer')
```

*Efficiency measured in reuse.*

Answer (score 0):

If your intent is DRY -- as in not repeating something and introducing more chance for error --
What about something like this:

```
cast={}
for title in ('Director','Prodcer','Writer'):
    name=get_element_or_none(title_node, title)
    if name:
        cast [title]=[x.strip() for x in name.split(',')]
```